# I keep getting this warning (The type parameter T is hiding the type T)

Tags: java

I have this method that is supposed to be able to accept all objects that extend from MyInteger. However i keep getting the warning "The type parameter T is hiding the type T".

```
public <T extends MyInteger> void removeZero(List<T> myList) {
        
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        if (MyInteger.isZero(myList.get(i))) {
            myList.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried getting rid of the first T in the signature but then the method doesn't now which objects it should accept.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but how can i find it i don't see it anywhere

Comment: What class is `removeZero` a member of? Does it have any type parameters?

Comment: It is part of a class called Utility this is how it looks, "public class Utility <T extends Comparable<T>>"

Comment: You have a type parameter `T` for the class surrounding this code. You either don't need to parameterize this method (with `<T extends MyInteger>`), or you need to use a different type parameter name, rather than `T` again.

Comment: `public class Utility <T extends Comparable<T>>` ← This defines a typer argument named `T`.  `public <T extends MyInteger> void removeZero` ← This defines *another* independent type argument named `T`, which means it is impossible for that method to make use of the class-level `T`.

Comment: Of course if that's what you intended, ignore the warning. But it's easy enough to fix without harming anything.